# Looping through serial port (COM port) in VB.NET and detect the correct port which is used by device

Tags: .net, vb.net, io, serial-port, port-scanning

Ok let me give you the details of the software and applications i am using:

- **Windows 7 Professional Edition**
- **Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2010**
- **VB.NET**
- **.NET 4.0 Framework**

My device is a simple data transmitter device which gets data inputted by the user like, name, age, gender and then it is transmitted to the PC software.

I already have the source code of the PC software which is in `C#` and i am a VB guy. I have gone through many tutorials on internet to learn serial port communication but i think maybe i am unable to get the logic or maybe that was not the right thing for my project. SO i need help from you people.

i have searched a lot on internet and found few resources which explains, how exactly i can communicate with serial ports, but none of these are working for me:

1. [COM port made simple with VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5131/COM-port-made-simple-with-VB-NET)
2. [Serial Port Communication in VB.NET](http://www.codeworks.it/net/VBNetRs232.htm)
3. [Serial Port Interfacing with VB.net 2010](http://tiktakx.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/serial-port-interfacing-with-vb-net-2010/)
4. [Serial COM Port Communication](http://www.innovatic.dk/knowledg/SerialCOM/SerialCOM.htm)

The previous software use to scan all available `IO` `PORTS` and Evaluates the incoming data from the serial ports. Finally, it detects the device on the basis of this data.

The Software is set for `BaudRate = 19200` `DataBits = 8` `StopBits = StopBits.One` `Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` `DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(portDataReceived)`

However with the tutorials i understood the terminologies specified here, but how to exactly communicate with the device and to check which port is the correct one is still a question.

So what i understood is required for me is to:

1. Loop through all available communication ports
2. Receive the data being sent by them
3. Then analyze that data and match with the standard data of the source code (provided to me)
4. And if the correct port is recognized then start receiving data from it.

What i need is an insight of you people on exactly what resource is required as i have been searching and reading for a long time and could not able to get exactly what i am looking for. Maybe i am unaware with the logic and the topic, so if the right resource is visible still i am ignoring it. Its just that i am a newbie in Serial Port communications.

Also, maybe there are many other question that you may require from my side to help me with this question and i have not produced you. So please let me know what all information you need from me, i will be try to get you if i can.

**EDIT-1**

I have used an `Port Monitoring Software` which gave me this raw data and it thrilled me...

[image]

Comment: This will be abundantly easier if you can have the user specify what port the device is connected to. Otherwise, you'll need to open each port in turn, wait for data (or send a message requesting data and then wait), analyze it, etc.

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like the device is using a binary protocol of some sort. You'll need the acquire the spec for this protocol in order to use this device.

Comment: @JonB ok but from where i can get this protocol? Do i need to connect with the manufacturer of the device? or as i am having the source code of the running software in C#, is there possibility that i can get the information about the protocol from in there?

Comment: If this c# source code is for communicating with this device, then that may be all you need. If not, then you need to contact the manufacturer. There may be an API document posted on their website. Or it may be proprietary and they won't give it to you.

Comment: @JonB Thanks for the help let me explore more on source code...

Answer (score 3):

What you propose (opening each port and attempting communication) is exactly what you need to do.

There is no standard way of doing this.  It depends on the device.  Nobody can tell you how to do this without knowing the protocol used to communicate with your device.  There is nothing special about a serial port... it just sends and receives data.  The protocol implementation is up to you.

Comment: When you say protocol, then what exactly i need to know about? Is there any kind of device knowledge is required?

Comment: @GoldenHeat, Yes, you need to know the protocol of the device.  What the format is for data being sent and received.

Comment: ok what i can understand maybe is the kind of data the device is transmitting, for that i have used a monitoring software which show this to me.... in `EDIT 1`

Comment: @GoldenHeat, You expect us to decode a protocol for you?  We don't even know what kind of device this is, don't have a big enough sample of data, and don't even know from your screenshot which side is transmitting and receiving.  I'm sorry, but nobody here is going to help you.  I thought your question was how to find a device attached to a serial port.

Comment: hmm i think i am getting your point, so to get the details of the protocol do i need to contact the device manufacturer? or if i am having the source code in `C#` and it is perfectly working fine then it maybe possible that the information related to the protocol is available there that i can find out and understand? I am stuck and really need a guidance. :|

Comment: Yes, contact the manufacturer and get the protocol spec.  If you have the source code from them, then simply read through it to figure out the protocol.  Chances are, there is a nice class you can drop right into your project.